# No module named 'pandas' issue, using Jupyter Notebook on Mac OS X

Tags: python, pandas, macos, pip, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import pandas to use in a Jupyter Notebook that I locally installed using Homebrew on my MacBook Pro. I installed pandas using pip, which I downloaded and installed using python3 get-pip.py. I have made sure that pip, python3 and python are all in the PATH, as well as Jupyter. Also, in the same script as I am trying to import pandas, I do a pip install of pandas, and it tells me I already have it, and the next line it tells me I do not? Attached is a screenshot of the notebook, any help is greatly appreciated. I really need to be able to use pandas for the project I am working on. Thank you.[pandas module not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R1k2.png)

```py
    !pip install pandas
    import pandas as pd

Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pandas) (1.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6b7405621ef2> in <module>
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install pandas')
----> 2 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

```py
    import sys; print(sys.path)

    import pandas as pd

['/Users/wbiscan/Documents', '/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/2.2.5/libexec/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/2.2.5/libexec/lib/python3.8', '/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/2.2.5/libexec/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8', '', '/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/2.2.5/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/2.2.5/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/Users/wbiscan/.ipython']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8cf22b110223> in <module>
      2 
      3 
----> 4 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Comment: Please do not include screenshots of code, post the code you are running as part of the question

Comment: What is the reason for this?

Comment: Some users cannot access image hosting sites, myself included

Comment: Understood, will fix

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! Copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read.

Comment: I believe I fixed it

Comment: Yep, thanks, nice!

Comment: what is output from `pip -V`? Is this the same as `python -m pip -V`? And in your notebook, are you able to see what the output of `sys.path` is?

Comment: pip -V gives: pip 20.2.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

Comment: and python -m pip -V gives: pip 20.2.2 from /Users/wbiscan/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

Comment: not in the notebook, it tells me "name 'sys' is not defined"

Comment: Then there's your issue, the running python is different than the python you are installing packages to. You'll need to run `import sys; print(sys.path)` to check the path value

Comment: when I run that here is what I get

Comment: I will edit my post to show what happens when I run import sys; print(sys.path)

Comment: Try `python -m pip install pandas`.

Comment: you're saying to run that in my terminal? Because when I do and relaunch Jupyter notebook and create a new notebook and try importing pandas I get the same issue. The jupyter notebook is python3 if that matters

Comment: Is jupyter using your python 3.8 instance?

Comment: I don't think that it is, I believe it is using 2.7.16.

Comment: but to be honest I don't exactly know, how could I find this out?